# Codeigniter Query Builder Joins

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, query-builder

This is a code snippet from my model.

```
public function story_profile($story_id){   
$this->db->select();
$this->db->from('story');
$this->db->where('story_id',$story_id);
$query = $this->db->get()->result();

foreach($query as $row){
$data['details'][$row->story_id]['title'] = $row->story_title;
$data['details'][$row->story_id]['synopsis'] = $row->synopsis;
$data['details'][$row->story_id]['date'] = $row->date_added;

    $this->db->select('story_genre.genre_id,genre_name');
    $this->db->from('story_genre');
    $this->db->join('genre', 'genre.genre_id = story_genre.genre_id');
    $this->db->where('story_id', $story_id);
    $query = $this->db->get()->result();

    foreach($query as $row){
    $data['genre'][$row->genre_id] = $row->genre_name;}

    $this->db->select('story_tag.tag_id,tag_name');
    $this->db->from('story_tag');
    $this->db->join('tags', 'tags.tag_id = story_tag.tag_id');
    $this->db->where('story_id', $story_id);
    $query = $this->db->get()->result();

    foreach($query as $row){
    $data['tags'][$row->tag_id] = $row->tag_name;}

    $this->db->select('story_content_warning.content_warning_id,content_warning_name');
    $this->db->from('story_content_warning');
    $this->db->join('content_warning', 'content_warning.content_warning_id = story_content_warning.content_warning_id');
    $this->db->where('story_id', $story_id);
    $query = $this->db->get()->result();

    foreach($query as $row){
    $data['content_warning'][$row->content_warning_id] = $row->content_warning_name;}
}
print_r($data);

$this->db->select();
$this->db->from('story');
$this->db->join('story_genre','story_genre.story_id = story.story_id');
$this->db->join('story_tag','story_tag.story_id = story.story_id');
$this->db->join('story_content_warning','story_content_warning.story_id = story.story_id');
$this->db->where('story.story_id',$story_id);
$query = $this->db->get()->result(); 

print_r($query);
```

My tables are story,story_genre,story_tags,story_content_warning,genre,tags,content_warning.

The genre,tags,content_warning tables i used to control the genre,tags, and content warning. If i were to post a story, in the form where i can select my genre,tags,content_warning, i fetch them from the above 3 tables and foreach loop them in the view. So there's no unexpected genre,tag,content_warning suddenly added. They also contains the column 'id and name'.

the story_genre,story_tags,_story_content_warning contains the columns, 'id, story_id, genre/tag/content id'

Anyway, my question is, which of the above code is 'more correct/acceptable'.

My problem with the multiple joins one is that it loops itself the n times of joins. So if i joined 4 tables the `$query results` loops itself n times of join. So i made another query where i broke it up into a procedure where i got the details first then the genre then the tags then the content warning.

EDIT: i forgot to add, i also have to add my 'chapters' table here.

I think its fine to multiple join tables that only have 1 row as result. I was wrong when i said it loops n amount of times table joined but it loops for the amount of rows returned.

I setup my table to be story(1) - (1)story_genre but there are multiple rows. as there are multiple genre to 1 story.

Comment: Hey there welcome to stack. We don't really just write things for people but rather we help with debugging and fixing issues. If you post what you have tried to accomplish ajax pagination someone might be able to help. With that being said, what you are asking seems to me like essentially recreating a datatables situation. Look over a library called ignited datatables

Comment: I really don't know where to start.

How do i know which pagination link i am clicking on? Should i make multiple ajax functions for each pagination?

Comment: Just use datatables and ignited datatables lib for ci. It'll be more robust than any solution you or I will be able to come up with.

Comment: whats the difference between the two? is ignited datatables exclusive to codeigniter?

Comment: I found it on github but idk how to use github. Is there a dedicate website for it to show how to install it and apply it?

Nvm, i found it. i just had to scroll downwards for description.

Comment: @ALEX can you reread my question?

Comment: sql isn't my specialty. sorry :(